# Where are fetch() and FormData() defined?

Tags: react-native

I'm using react-native and [standardjs](http://standardjs.com/).

Standard reports that both `fetch` and `FormData` are undefined when I use them, which is true.  However, I can't figure out where either of these symbols are defined.  I can't seem to import them from either react or react-native modules.

What import statement should I use to import `fetch` and `FormData`?

Comment: fetch comes with react-native core and you dont need to import it to use it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

fetch and FormData are provided as global polyfill for react-native. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html#content

Something like this to your package.json will prevent standardjs complaining about undefined variables

```
{
  "standard": {
    "globals": [ "fetch", "FormData" ]
  }
}
```